# frida returning wrong overload of android method

Tags: android, java, frida

im trying to hook the C6494a method has 2 parameters the ge6 object and a activity object whenever i try to hook this method with a hook overload that contains both ge6 and the activity object frida throws a error saying the overload is incorrect (view image2)

[image: image1]

this is the hook im using to hook the constructor

```
Java.use("com.ge6$a").$init.overload('com.ge6', 'android.app.Activity').implementation = function(a, b){
    }
```

and this is the error frida throws when using the above hook

```
Error: ge6$a(): specified argument types do not match any of:
        .overload('android.app.Activity')
    at X (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:569)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:899)
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-2.js:76)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:250)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:242)
    at apply (native)
    at ne (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:620)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:598)
```

and even if i set the overload without the ge6 object

```
Java.use("com.ge6$a").$init.overload('android.app.Activity').implementation = function(a){
    }
```

frida throws this error instead

```
Error: Cast from 'com.ge6' to 'android.app.Activity' isn't possible
    at cast (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:131)
    at fromJni (/_java.js)
    at ne (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:617)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:598)
```

also trying to create a new object of this subclass throws this issue instead

```
Process crashed: Trace/BPT trap

***
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:11/RSR1.201013.001/6903271:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2022-07-24 18:37:32+0100
pid: 15013, tid: 15013, name: nalds.mobileapp  >>> com.mcdonalds.mobileapp <<<
uid: 10153
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0xffaadb28
    from void com.ge6.a(android.app.Activity, com.ge6$b)'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00003aa5  ecx 00003aa5  edx 00000006
    edi f005e81e  esi ffaad310
    ebp f237ab90  esp ffaad2b8  eip f237ab99
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
      #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so!libc.so (offset 0x59000) (syscall+40) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #02 pc 00076511  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so!libc.so (offset 0x75000) (abort+209) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #03 pc 0000040e  <anonymous:e3a29000>
***
```

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of code and terminal output, instead post everything as text and format it as code. This is the general recommendation and in your case the screen shots are partially so bat that they are hard to read. Please edit your question and change it as proposed.

Comment: @Robert i have edited the post as proposed, yes i am trying to hook the constructor not a class method also calling it throws a new issue i have included it in the post

Comment: First your hooking code of a constructor needs to call and return the original constructor: https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets#hook-constructor and second: are you sure you have the correct Activity class? Check the imports in Jadx, because there can be more classes in different packages of that name.

Comment: is it possible the second error is not a hooking error, but an error that happens when the app calls that class? try `return this.$new(a);` - or add a console.log after hooking to see if it works

Comment: it turns out i decompiled a apk version and forgot to install it on the emulator so i was hooking a older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as embarrassing as this is turns out the installed version of the app on the emulator is slightly older than the one i decompiled with jadx-gui installing the same version fixed this